# .NET regular expression reserved characters

Tags: .net, regex

Where is the set of .NET regular expression reserved characters?

Edit: This looks like it might be it.  Thanks sugarman.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

Comment: Why? Just use @ in front of your opening quote and you do not need to worry about escaping characters

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm not clear on what you're asking.

Comment: @ is only good for making C# strings.  It doesn't help you put RegEx reserved characters into RegEx patterns.

Comment: You're not trying to reinvent `Regex.Escape`, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link goes to the exact page that answers the question.  (The answer comes from sugarman.  If sugarman wants to post the answer it will be selected.)

[character escapes supported by regular expressions in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e.aspx)

From that link there is a table entry that says, .NET regular expression chars match themselves except for the following:

. $ ^ { [ ( | ) * + ? \

Thus, these are the reserved chars of .NET regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at Regex.Escape(). You pass the function a string and it will escape any reserved regex characters to be interpreted as literals. Credit to this answer goes to Gabe who commented on the OP's post, I'm just making it an answer so others don't possibly miss it.

Comment: Yes thanks, I missed that semi-snarky (but useful) comment as well. And it is the beauty of SO that I can find the answer to a simple question like this quickly. Yes, I could have hunted the MS lit, but time is $ to me. And .Escape() didn't help me here, but it is good to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a good starting point for what you're looking for:

[.NET Framework Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)